# NHibernate 2.1.2 connection open upon factory.OpenSession()?

Tags: nhibernate, connection, isession

When I open a session with

`var session = factory.OpenSession();`

and check session.Connection.State it is Open. The "Connection" is of type SqlConnection.
This means that by creating the session the connection is automatically opened, which I thought that with NH isn't the case. Shouldn't this be closed until NH determines the optimal time for flush? What am I doing wrong?

The hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test; Integrated Security=SSPI</property>
    <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what actually happens is that NHibernate *creates and opens* a connection when you first say `session.Connection` (if the session didn't already have a connection, of course)